Can one say about ramification at particular level of tower of extensions based on information at preceding and succeeding levels?
Let $K$ be an unramified extension of the $p$-adic number field $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Suppose we have a tower of extensions $$K=:K(u_0) \subset K(u_1) \subset K(u_2) \subset K(u_3) \subset \cdots \subset K(u_n) \subset \cdots $$ such that $f(u_n)=0$ for a fixed polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $p^5$. And $u_n$ are dependent by the relation $u_n=\sqrt[p^5]{u_{n-1}}$.

Suppose $K(u_1)/K$ is totally ramified and $K(u_n)/ K(u_{n-1})$ is totally ramified for $n \geq 3$.


So we have total ramification at the first level, and the third level onwards.
Can we say about ramification of the extension $K(u_2)/K(u_1)$?

Since the successive extensions after 3rd level is totally ramified, $K(u_n)/K(u_2)$ is also totally ramified.
Also given that $K(u_1)/K$ is totally ramified.
If we had $K(u_n)/K$ totally ramified, it would force $K(u_2)/K(u_1)$ to be totally ramified.
Since the algebraic elements $u_n$ are satisfying the same polynomial, and since $K(u_n)/ K(u_{n-1})$ is totally ramified for $n \geq 3$, I guess for the same reason $K(u_2)/K(u_1)$ totally ramified. Though I am not sure about it.
I appreciate your help. Thanks
